# Sybase - Hanging when dropping non-existing index

Tags: database, sybase, sap-ase

I'm running sybase ASE `Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.0.3/EBF 17690 ESD#1.1 RELSE/P/Solaris AMD64/OS 5.10/ase1503/2681/64-bit/FBO/Thu Aug 20 15:37:40 2009` and facing a weird problem.

When dropping an index that doesn't exist, I'm getting an indefinite hanging:

```
1> sp_helpindex TABLE#DATA#DEALIRD_DBF
2> go
Object has the following indexes

 index_name  index_keys index_description    index_max_rows_per_page index_fillfactor index_reservepagegap index_created       index_local
 ----------- ---------- -------------------- ----------------------- ---------------- -------------------- ------------------- ------------
 DEALIRD_ND0  M_NB      nonclustered, unique                       0                0                    0 Oct  1 2012 10:20AM Global Index

(1 row affected)
 index_ptn_name         index_ptn_seg
 ---------------------- -------------
 DEALIRD_ND0_2038047761 default

(1 row affected, return status = 0)
1> drop index TABLE#DATA#DEALIRD_DBF.WHATEVER
2> go
```

It hangs indefinitely after this.

From another session, I check what's running:

```
sqsh-2.1.3 Copyright (C) 1995-2001 Scott C. Gray
Portions Copyright (C) 2004 Michael Peppler
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
For more information type '\warranty'
1> sp_who
2> go | grep ENV0001182_14391729
   0   13 recv sleep LIMITS   LIMITS   mx1530vm        0 ENV0001182_14391729_1 tempdb     AWAITING COMMAND            0
   0   19 recv sleep INSTAL   INSTAL   mx1534vm        0 ENV0001182_14391729   tempdb     AWAITING COMMAND            0
   0   21 recv sleep INSTAL   INSTAL   mx1534vm        0 ENV0001182_14391729   tempdb     AWAITING COMMAND            0
   0   25 recv sleep LIMITS   LIMITS   mx1530vm        0 ENV0001182_14391729_1 tempdb     AWAITING COMMAND            0
   0  112 recv sleep LIMITS   LIMITS   mx1530vm        0 ENV0001182_14391729_1 tempdb     AWAITING COMMAND            0
   0  114 recv sleep LIMITS   LIMITS   mx1530vm        0 ENV0001182_14391729_1 tempdb     AWAITING COMMAND            0
   0  221 recv sleep INSTAL   INSTAL   mx1530vm        0 ENV0001182_14391729   tempdb     AWAITING COMMAND            0
   0  270 lock sleep INSTAL   INSTAL   NULL            0 ENV0001182_14391729   tempdb     DROP INDEX               6953
   0  271 running    sa       sa       NULL            0 ENV0001182_14391729   tempdb     INSERT                      0
   0  325 recv sleep LIMITS   LIMITS   mx1530vm        0 ENV0001182_14391729_1 tempdb     AWAITING COMMAND            0
1> dbcc traceon(3604)
2> go
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact a user with System Administrator (SA) role.
1> dbcc sqltext(270)
2> go
SQL Text: drop index TABLE#DATA#DEALIRD_DBF.WHATEVER

DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact a user with System Administrator (SA) role.
```

I've given this query a full day while I worked on something else just to make sure it doesn't end, but it just sits there.

Note that I'm not able to reproduce it with a fresh table:

```
1> create table OMX(SOMETHING NUMERIC(2,2))
2> go
1> sp_helpindex OMX
2> go
Object does not have any indexes.
(return status = 1)
1> drop index OMX.WHATEVER
2> go
Msg 3701, Level 11, State 3
Server 'MX1530VM', Line 1
Cannot drop the index 'OMX.WHATEVER', because it doesn't exist in the system catalogs.
```

Does anyone know how I can continue my analysis? I checked in sysindexes but didn't find an entry for it. I updated all statistics on the table but that didn't help.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Your session (spid 270) is in 'lock sleep' status. This means it's being blocked by another session. You need to find out what item is being locked that causes the blocking, which that blocking session is and what it's doing and why it does not release its locks. It looks like spid 6953 is causing the blocking.
Start with "sp_lock @verbose=1" to see which lock is causing the blocking.

Comment: Thanks for the help Rob. However I can't see an SPID 6953 running on the DB server when logged in as `sa`. What could be the source of this SPID?

Comment: In that case, best restart you ASE server as that may be a zombie process -- but it's difficult to tell. DO ensure that you have a recent ASE version with the latest patches. And check in your errorlog for stacktraces - when finding any, contact Sybase techsupport to see if it's a known problem (remedy will be: upgrade to the latest patch level)

Comment: Thank you Rob, I ended up restarting the whole machine for a different reason and it got me over my issue.